# Adding a dimming knob to a step up power supply

Tags: led, voltage-regulator, constant-current, dimming, brightness

I am a ME student with little EE knowledge, and I currently have a setup which includes a 12V SLA battery, a 100W LED chip and a constant-current constant-voltage step up converter. The board can be found here:

[http://www.amazon.com/DROK-Converter-Transformer-Regulator-Controller/dp/B00E8D7XYG/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00E8D7XYG)

I have adjusted the trim pots on the board to provide the LED with around 95W, as this is near it's maximum operating point. This is a portable floodlight project, and because the board is housed inside of the body, this trim pot is not adjustable during use.

My goal is to add a dimming switch that protrudes out of the body of the light that will vary the current (and thus voltage) given to the LED. My first thought is to introduce a logarithmic potentiometer into the circuit with resistors, as I understand that the LED current draw exponentially increases with increasing voltage. But the problem is that I have no idea how to go about determining which value of resistors or trim pot I will need or where this would be added to the circuit.

The overall thought idea is to have an additional switch that varies the current from 0A to my pre-applied value that was set using the board's trim pot. I have used an Arduino in the past to control an LED's brightness using PWM, but this isn't ideal because I would like this design to be as simple as possible.

Thanks

Comment: Well you understand that if your source is supplying 95W and you try to only let the LED consume, say 40W, the potentiometer must turn the difference into heat. This is exactly why PWM systems are used, because there isn't a resistive element wasting heat; instead a transistor is turning on to nearly 0 ohms and shutting off to nearly infinite resistance. You're going to need a PWM at this power level. You may want to look at a purpose built LED dimmer if you want something simple.

Comment: So if I remember correctly from the last time I fiddled with this, as I adjusted the output on the board via the trim pots, the current draw on the battery varied. So I came to the conclusion that the board has a transistor doing exactly what you are describing, therefore it isn't wasting energy. It there not a way I can make the current trim pot adjustable off of the board?

Comment: Oh I think I misunderstood what you were trying to do. I guess if you want to *replace* the onboard pot with your new pot, sure, that might work. It's hard to say since it depends on how the regulator works. The thing is, there are off the shelf controllers designed for this, I'd strongly recommend one of those before tinkering with this one. This power level is not something to be toyed around with, on a low-cost (read: potentially low quality, low-safety) regulator board.

Comment: Big raw LED modules want to have their *current* regulated, not their voltage. Trying to adjust brightness by setting the voltage applied to the module is a bad idea. If you replace your power supply's *current* control trimpot with your exterrnal potentiometer of the same value, you should be fine.

Comment: update to my earlier comment - you might want to use put a resistor in series with the external pot to limit the top-end of the adjustment to whatever the LED module can handle.

Comment: @brhans Thanks guys for the answers. What I gather from the responses: Measure the resistance across the trim pot as it is currently set where I want it. It seems that the pot is a 10-200Mohm 0.5W pot, so I should replace it with a conventional (possibly logarithmic, I would like an very uniform dimming effect) 200Mohm pot. Add a series resistor with new pot that equals 200Mohm minus the value that its currently set at. This would ensure that my pre-determined maximum current would never be reached.

Comment: Yes, except that's a 200k pot, not 200M. Its resistance code is 204 and should be read like any 3-color-banded resistor, so 20x10^4. Logarithmic is a good idea since perceived brightness is logarithmic(-ish).

Answer (score 1):

> This is a portable floodlight project, and because the board is housed
>   inside of the body, this trim pot is not adjustable during use.

Inspect the trim pot and if necessary measure it after removing it from the circuit. Get a conventional pot of the same value and maybe even a multiturn type so you can control things more smoothly. Solder it in place (using short wires) and it should work just fine.

If the trim pot does not give enough range then I'd strongly consider using a different controller.

Answer (score 0):

To replace a potentiometer with a fixed minimum (or maximum) point you can use the diagram below.  You would select the extra resistor (R3) to setup the desired min/max point.  (To switch from a minimum to maximum control just move the fixed resistor onto the opposite side leg,  for e.g.: From A to B.)

You may need to experiment a bit to determine the correct side to place the fixed resistor.  It is also a good idea to preset the replacement potentiometer near its center point to avoid over powering the device at first power on, just use a ohm meter to find this.

Note that getting an exact total where (R2+R3)=R1 is likely not an absolute requirement, though the total should be close to insure the approximate design parameters.

.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fp19Nd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you control the ***current*** rather than the *voltage* you shouldn't need a logarithmic pot as brightness will be proportional to *current*. A **linear pot** will suffice and also give a more natural looking response.

The other answers about 200k, desoldering the original pot and Andy's answer about inserting a fixed resistor (or even the original pot) as a fixed maximum are correct.